# I am unable to download the TIDYR R package

Tags: r, package, tidyr

```
install.packages("tidyr")
```

`tidyr` does not download. I enclose below the details that appear in the R console.

```
Installing package into ‘/home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux/4.2’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘purrr’, ‘stringr’

trying URL 'https://company_path/rib/purrr_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 536513 bytes (523 KB)
================================================== downloaded 523 KB

trying URL 'https://rstudiopm.companyname.com/CRAN/__linux__/..../stringr_1.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 324813 bytes (317 KB)
================================================== downloaded 317 KB

trying URL 'https://rstudiopm.companyname.com/CRAN/__linux__/..../tidyr_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1273984 bytes (1.2 MB)
================================================== downloaded 1.2 MB

Error in library(envsetup) : there is no package called ‘envsetup’

Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘purrr’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(envsetup) : there is no package called ‘envsetup’
Execution halted

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(envsetup) : there is no package called ‘envsetup’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/.../downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try `install.packages("envsetup")` first.

Comment: It should have at least changed the error message. What does it say now?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not install envsetup either

Comment: This is the error for envsetup.

Error in library(envsetup) : there is no package called ‘envsetup’ Execution halted ......... The downloaded source packages are in ‘/tmp/RtmpMJFKT4/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘stringr’ is imported by ‘kableExtra’ so cannot be unloaded

Comment: So you are not installing from the public CRAN sites, you are installing from rstudiopm.companyname.com? The `envsetup` is not a CRAN package so that must be unique to your company. You should probably contact your own IT support because it would be impossible for us to know how things are setup on your private company network.

Comment: Try using this: `install.packages("tidyr", dependencies = TRUE)` If it asks about installing packages that require compilation, for now, say NO. (You need to have other libraries loaded when using compilation.) Let me know if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Try using this: `install.packages("tidyr", dependencies = TRUE)` If it asks about installing packages that require compilation, for now, say NO. (You need to have other libraries loaded when using compilation.) Let me know if this doesn't work.

[Credit: Kat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76557044/i-am-unable-to-download-the-tidyr-r-package#comment134981407_76557044)